# SQL to group by date range of various rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Really hard to even explain this question. I have data sets in SQL Server 2008 that contain rows with a start and end date which can overlap dates by rows. I am trying to figure out a simple query without the use of a cursor to group these into distinct possible ranges.

I have a query that will handle some situations but not all.

**Example 1:**

In this example, product A runs for about 30 days but product B runs for the entire year. I need the distinct list of date ranges. Day 1 - 30, Day 30 - 365

```
Data in Table
product  start       end
-------  ----------  ----------
A        09/02/2015  10/01/2015
B        09/02/2015  08/31/2016

Desired Query Result
start       end
----------  ----------
09/02/2015  10/01/2015
10/01/2015  08/31/2016
```

**Example 2:**

This example is similar to Example 1 above but product A already has two ranges defined. The result of the query would be the same, 2 date ranges. Day 1 - 30, Day 30 - 365

```
Data in Table
product  start       end
-------  ----------  ----------
A        09/02/2015  10/01/2015
A        10/01/2015  08/31/2016
B        09/02/2015  08/31/2016

Desired Query Result
start       end
----------  ----------
09/02/2015  10/01/2015
10/01/2015  08/31/2016
```

**Current Query**

This very simple query works on example 2 because there are two periods already defined. Cannot figure out how to make it work in example 1.

```
select start_on, min(end_on)
from product p
group by start_on
order by start_on
```

Any help would be much appreciated! I really prefer not to use a cursor. I have been thinking about a over/partition by bu so far have not been able to make any progress on it.

Comment: Could you expand your sample when ranges are contain exactly? Like what will be the result when `A` start with `01/01/2015`? Also a larger sample will be helpfull.

Comment: I have added my answer with screenshot of output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
>WITH dates (dt) as
>(
>SELECT start [dt] from product
>UNION
>SELECT [end] [dt] from product)
>
>SELECT d1.dt [start_on], 
>>  (select min(d2.dt) from dates d2 where d2.dt > d1.dt) [end_on]
>FROM dates d1
>WHERE not (select min(d2.dt) from dates d2 where d2.dt > d1.dt) is NULL

>ORDER BY [dt]
```

Comment: Right on the money! And very simple query as well. I put it in a fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d4bce/2/0 if anyone else cares to see.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

```
SELECT DISTINCT start_on, end_on
FROM (
  SELECT start_on, end_on
  FROM product
  UNION
  SELECT p1.end_on AS start_on, p2.end_on
  FROM product p1, product p2
  WHERE p1.start_on = p2.start_on
  AND p1.end_on < p2.end_on
)
```

Comment: The problem is you need split ranges. Not sure if you code do that

Comment: SQL isn't liking this syntax. I am assuming it has something to do with the union inside the sub select?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
DECLARE @t TABLE 

(PRODUCT CHAR(1)
,START DATE
,[END] DATE
)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES ('A','09/02/2015','10/01/2015')
                     ,('B','09/02/2015','08/31/2016')
                     ,('C','09/02/2015','12/31/2016')
                     ,('D','09/02/2015','10/21/2017')

                     SELECT * FROM @t /*See sample data*/

    SELECT START,[END]
    FROM ( SELECT START, [END], ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY START ORDER BY START ASC) Rn
           FROM @t) X
           WHERE X.Rn = 1           /*Pick the first record with initial start date*/
    UNION


    SELECT X.END1, X.END2
    FROM
    (
    SELECT DISTINCT t1.[END] END1,t2.[END] END2, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t1.[END] ORDER BY T1.[END], T2.[END]) Rn /*Partition by t1.END date to get unique combinations ranked as 1 */
    FROM @t t1
     JOIN @t t2                         /*Self join on @t to pull distinct END date combination. Select the first End date (from t1) as Start Date and Second End Date (from t2) as End Date */
     ON t1.START = t2.START
     WHERE t1.[END] < t2.[END]          /*Make sure t1.END date is less than t2.END date */
     )X
     WHERE X.Rn = 1 /*Pull the unique combination of t1.END date (which is technically the new Start date */
```

[image: Expected Output]

Comment: Please could you include some comments about your code.

Comment: Isn't redundant `t1.end`  <> and < `t2.end` ?

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza - I have added comments. Also removed the unnecessary filter that I just noticed.

Comment: I have a doubt about this [_CASE_](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/330f4/1)  where  range `E` is contain in `A` range, and aditional range is created. Of course not sure what will be OP requirement for that case.

Comment: This is more on the lines of the path I was heading down with the partition but it doesnt break up the date ranges like into their proper segments. @JuanCarlosOropeza fiddle above didnt break them up either. I could have not explained the desired result the best.